# Splitting a Dataframe column on Delimiter and retaining all other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the "raw_input" dataframe below. If you look at the "Summary" column. There is a 
   **delimiter ':'** that I would like to create two additional columns on, and append to the existing dataframe

I would like to split that "Summary" column into two columns('Work
   Package' and 'Task')

I can split the delimiter using command below. But I don't know how to append/merge it back to the existing dataframe

```
split_data = pd.DataFrame(raw_input['Summary'].str.split(':',1).tolist(),columns=['Work Package','Task'])

print(raw_input)

         Key                                     Summary       Status                                        Description     Updated
0  XTBOW-310  Data Mgmt: Product Assesment and Selection  In Analysis  - To establish a provider for the solution of ...  2017-05-26
1  XTBOW-420       Data Mgmt: Vendor > CIBC Implemention          NaN  - Integrate with Vendor to fetch Corporate Act...  2017-05-19
2  XTBOW-421             Trade Migration: PVs and Greeks          NaN  - PVs and Greeks regression gap analysis betwe...  2017-05-19
3  XTBOW-422       Trade Migration: Reports (XTC vs XT2)          NaN                                                NaN  2017-05-19



print(split_data)

      Work Package                              Task
0        Data Mgmt   Product Assesment and Selection
1        Data Mgmt        Vendor > CIBC Implemention
2  Trade Migration                    PVs and Greeks
3  Trade Migration              Reports (XTC vs XT2)
```

Comment: `raw_input = pd.concat([raw_input, split_data], axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way:

```
In [11]: df[['Work Package','Task']] = df['Summary'].str.split(':',1, expand=True)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
         Key                                     Summary                                             Status Description  Updated  \
0  XTBOW-310  Data Mgmt: Product Assesment and Selection  In Analysis  - To establish a provider for the...  2017-05-26      NaN
1  XTBOW-420       Data Mgmt: Vendor > CIBC Implemention  NaN  - Integrate with Vendor to fetch Corporat...  2017-05-19      NaN
2  XTBOW-421             Trade Migration: PVs and Greeks  NaN  - PVs and Greeks regression gap analysis ...  2017-05-19      NaN
3  XTBOW-422       Trade Migration: Reports (XTC vs XT2)  NaN                                           ...  2017-05-19      NaN

      Work Package                              Task
0        Data Mgmt   Product Assesment and Selection
1        Data Mgmt        Vendor > CIBC Implemention
2  Trade Migration                    PVs and Greeks
3  Trade Migration              Reports (XTC vs XT2)
```